# clear inner html of span using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to compare pass and confirm password text field. Its working fine but the issue is if enter mismatch password its showing error ' password do not match' and after that if i match the password its showing 'password match' next to old error. so its displaying like 'password do not match password match'(please see the image for reference.. [***Error Image***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC9MN.jpg)

. How to clear the span before i show the message.

```
   $(confPassword).live('blur', function() {
    alert(password.value);
    if (password.value != 'Password') {
        alert("hi");
        if (password.value == confPassword.value) {
            alert("match");
            setupConfirmControl(confPassword, astConfPassword, lblConfPassword, true);
        }
        else {
            alert("dont match");
            setupConfirmControl(confPassword, astConfPassword, lblConfPassword, false);
        }
    }
});

function setupConfirmControl(elemObj, id, labelTxt, addToParent) {
    var ConfirmPass = document.createElement('span');
    ConfirmPass.setAttribute('class', 'ClsConfirmPass');
    ConfirmPass.setAttribute('id', 'span' + id);
    ConfirmPass.innerHTML = '';
    if (addToParent) {
        ConfirmPass.innerHTML = 'Passwords match';
        elemObj.parentNode.insertBefore(ConfirmPass, elemObj);
    }
    else {
        ConfirmPass.innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
        elemObj.parentNode.insertBefore(ConfirmPass, elemObj);
    }
    showConfirmPassWord(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a *new* `span` every time within your function, simply check if a span exists and, if it does, use that span:

```
function setupConfirmControl(elemObj, id, labelTxt, addToParent) {
    var ConfirmPass = document.getElementById('span' + id);
    if (!ConfirmPass){
        ConfirmPass = document.createElement('span');
        ConfirmPass.setAttribute('class', 'ClsConfirmPass');
        ConfirmPass.setAttribute('id', 'span' + id);
        ConfirmPass.innerHTML = '';
    }

    if (addToParent) {
        ConfirmPass.innerHTML = 'Passwords match';
        elemObj.parentNode.insertBefore(ConfirmPass, elemObj);
    }
    else {
        ConfirmPass.innerHTML = 'Passwords do not match';
        elemObj.parentNode.insertBefore(ConfirmPass, elemObj);
    }
    showConfirmPassWord(id);
}
```

This effectively assigns the previously-created `span` element (of `id` equal to `'span' + id`, assuming those are constant for error messages for the same field). And then, if there's no element of that `id` in the document (the `!ConfirmPass`), creates the element.

This way any previously-written content in the `span` will be over-written by setting the `innerHTML`.

Comment: You're *very* welcome; I'm glad to have been of help, and, may I add, thank *you* for the accept! =)